# How to turn 1D array into symmetrical 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gaussian, gaussianblur

I have a symmetrical 1D numpy array, for example, something like this:

```
0 1 2 1 0
```

How could I turn this into a 3D array (kinda similar to a gaussian kernel), with the value 2 at the center?

As an example of what I mean (though the math is likely not right), in 2D this would be something like this (though I need it to be 3D):

```
0   0   0   0   0
0  0.5  1  0.5  0
0   1   2   1   0
0  0.5  1  0.5  0
0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: FYI: A *gaussian* kernel is a very specific thing.  Your data is not a gaussian kernel. </pedantic>

Answer (score 1):

Acknowledging that this is *not* a Gaussian kernel, here's how you calculate *it*:

```
center = a[a.size // 2]
(a[:,    np.newaxis].repeat(a.size, axis=1) * a)\
  [:, :, np.newaxis].repeat(a.size, axis=2) * a \
/ center ** 2
```

(Not gonna paste the whole output here.)